# How use like for two fields and one value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have query like this :

```
select * from users where `firstname` like '%jack%' or `lastname` like '%Mr green%'
```

But this code is not suitable when I want to find person that her first name is `jack` and her last name is `Mr green` or firstname is jack Mr and lastname is green.
in other  word i have one textbox and user fill this textbox with firstname and lastname with one space between them , and i want search in users table and find users that search with searcher (searcher is who fill textbox).
Is there way to use `like` for two columns ?

Comment: because i can find person that her name is 'jack Mr green' in one query.

Comment: Isn't it what you wanted? Can you give as test data and result what you want to be achieved, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think 
if name is value 
you can use this

```
 (`firstname` like '%value%' or `lastname` like '%value%' or concat(firstname,' ', lastname) LIKE '%value%')
```

Comment: The only way `concat` would make a difference is if first name was `jack mr` and last name was `green`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `OR` to `AND`:

```
select * from users
where `firstname` like '%jack%'
AND `lastname` like '%Mr green%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you're asking, but I think that you want is to have first name OR last name match (*but not both at the same time*). In that case:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `users`
WHERE 
    (
        `firstname` LIKE '%jack%'
        AND
        `lastname` NOT LIKE '%Mr green%'
    )
    OR
    (
        `firstname` NOT LIKE '%jack%'
        AND
        `lastname` LIKE '%Mr green%' 
    )
```